# Angular routing - Default child route being activated at root route level

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am having this problem in my Angular 5 application where a child route is getting activated at a router-outlet that should enable a root route. I am hoping someone reading this will be able to spot the problem in my route definitions that I have not been able to spot for the last couple of days.

My Angular application has 3 nested route-levels. I have the routes defined in separate modules.

In the app module, I have defined the root routes as:

```
const mainRoutes: Route[] = [
    {
        path: '', redirectTo: 'mainApp', pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'mainApp', canActivate: [AuthGuardService], component: TabbarComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'home', canActivate: [AuthGuardService], component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'books', canActivate: [AuthGuardService], loadChildren: () => BookshModule },
            { path: 'authors', canActivate: [AuthGuardService], loadChildren: () => AuthorsModule },
            { path: 'research-articles', canActivate: [AuthGuardService], loadChildren: () => ResArticlesModule },
        ]
    },
    {
        path: 'login', component: LoginComponent
    },    
    {
        path: '**', redirectTo: 'mainApp', pathMatch: 'full'
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(mainRoutes, { enableTracing: false })
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
```

For the BooksModule (as also the AuthorsModule and ResArticlesModule), the routes look like:

```
const bookroutes: Route[] = [
    {
        path: '', component: BooksComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'fiction',  canActivate: [AuthGuardService], component: FictionComponent },
            { path: 'non-fiction',  canActivate: [AuthGuardService], component: NonFictionComponent },
            { path: 'autobiographies',  canActivate: [AuthGuardService], component: AutoBiographiesComponent }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(bookroutes)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
```

What happens is that when the appication loads, the root router-outlet loads the default route of the bookroutes at the top-most router-outlet where I expect the mainApp route from the root routes to be displayed. Don't quite know why that is happening.

If I change the default book route to non-default (that is, change

```
 path: ''
```

to

```
 path: 'books'
```

), it then loads the default route of ResArticlesModule. If I change the default route there too, it loads the default route of the 'AuthorsModule'. So for some reason, the router is loading the first available default child route where a root route is expected.

I am sure this is an artifact of misconfigured routing on my part. Can someone help me find what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the order of the `import` of the  Modules or Routing Modules? Are you including the book routes before the mainApp Routes?

Comment: Yes, the child routes are imported first. Does that make a difference? Here's the sequence in my app module:
           .
    AuthorsModule,
    BooksModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
           .
           .

Comment: what happens if you change the order of the import, e.g. put AppRoutingModule first.

Comment: Create sample in stackblitz that will help to check the actual issue.

Comment: Joshvito, Yes that was it. I changed the order to have the root routing module first, then the modules that brought in the child routes and it fixed everything.

Comment: Joshvito, could you provide your comment as an answer, so that I can accept it? I can't seem to be able to figure out how to accept your current answer/comment.